# C++ tracing getline

Tags: c++, getline

**User Input:**

Hello My

Name Is Jake

```
string a, b, c, d;

getline(cin, a);
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
getline(cin, d);
cout << a << b << c << d;
```

**Answer:** Hello MyName Is Jake

I am wondering why the getline takes in only one space when there are other spaces left in the buffer.

**Input:**

Hello(space)My(/n)

Name(space)Is(space)Jake(/n)

I understand that the /n after "My" is discarded because of the getline, so why doesnt the second getline take in the 3 spaces that are in the buffer instead of only one?

Comment: Input Hello(space)My(space)(/n)Name(space)Is(space)Jake(/n)
or Hello(space)My(/n)(space)Name(space)Is(space)Jake(/n)

in which case it's going to probably return "hello my name is" because it's looking for 4 inputs seperated by spaces not new lines.

Comment: are you trying to have it read 'hello my name is jake' into 'hello, my, name, is, jake'? What exactly are you trying to do on it

Comment: I am code tracing